# Hover on mouse over rather than show transition on mouse out

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the images on my webpage show a different colour when I hover over them. Instead what is happening is that the images have this transparent colour and its showing the original picture when I hover over them.

Please can someone help with this:

```
.service-style-1 .service-perview figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -o-border-radius: 50%;
  -ms-border-radius: 50%;
  -khtml-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  -khtml-transition: all 0.2s linear;
  transition: all 0.2s linear;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 104px solid rgba(255, 109, 132, 0.5);
}

.service-style-1:hover .service-perview figcaption {
  border-width: 8px;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="carousel-services carousel-col-3 carousel">
    <div class="service-wrapper carousel-item">
      <div class="service service-style-1">
        <h3 class="service-title"><a href="single-product.html">Product</a></h3>
        <figure class="service-perview">
          <img src="images1.jpg" alt="Cakes">
          <figcaption></figcaption>
        </figure>
        <p class="service-description">Product1</p>
      </div>
      <!-- end of service -->
    </div>
    <!-- end of service wrappper -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your html as well

Comment: @LGSon Ive added it thanks

Comment: Can you please clarify the problem? Maybe consider sharing a demo on [JSFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: @Gofilord yep, I just want it to hover when I hover over it and at the moment it has a solid cover covering the image and uncovers when I hover over it.

Comment: @Gofilord the border uncovers the image on hover, I want the border to be invisible and cover the image on hover instead. Ive added the code here thanks: https://jsfiddle.net/xqup1jp0/

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this by making the border to 8px and then on the hover making it 104px